# Unable to use react-native-show-hide-toggle-box

Tags: react-native

I tried to implement react-native-show-hide-toggle-box for getting the toogle box but whenever i run the project I get an error:
(Unable to resolve module "./ToggleBoxStyle" from "node_modules/react-native-show-hide-toggle-box/ToggleBox.js")

This is the 1st time usage of this module for me and i am unable to get pass through it.

I checked the node module which contains the file ToogleBoxStyles and ToogleBox in the same directory, but when i went inside ToogleBox it is having this line:
**import styles from './ToggleBoxStyle'**

So how to make this work as i installed it by 
npm i native-show-hide-toggle-box --save

Basic importing of default export is showing error to me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { LayoutAnimation, View, Text, StatusBar, ScrollView, Picker, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import ToggleBox from 'react-native-show-hide-toggle-box'

export default class TimeSlot extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
  <Toggle label='Show me something' value='asd' style={{backgroundColor: '#ddd', borderBottomWidth: 1}}>
    <View style={{height: 300, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#eee'}}>
      <Text>Hello, how are you?</Text>
    </View>
  </Toggle>
</ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

From ToogleBox.js

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Animated} from 'react-native'

// external libs
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'

// styles
import styles from './ToggleBoxStyle'

How to make the above thing work for me?
```

Comment: can you check to see if `react-native-show-hide-toggle-box` is listed as a dependency instead of `native-show-hide-toggle-box`? and import `ToggleBox` instead of `Toggle`?

Comment: in package.json "react-native-show-hide-toggle-box": "^1.0.1" is there as a dependency and I mistakenly posted Toggle instead of ToggleBox(now I edited it correctly).

Comment: how about `<ToggleBox>` instead of `<Toggle>`?

Comment: no help It is returning the same error

Comment: instead of react-native-show-hide-toggle-box, react-native-tooglebox worked.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, this worked out with me. I used `import { ToggleBox } from 'react-native` instead of `import { ToggleBox } from 'react-native-show-hide-toggle-box'`.